# How to disable I2C pins in Raspberry Pi 3 (jessie)

Tags: gpio, pi-3, rpi.gpio, i2c

I need to use the SDA and SCL pins in the GPIO headers. How do I convert them to normal GPIO pins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They ARE normal GPIO pins, configured by default as inputs, unless you have configured them otherwise.

The only difference from other GPIO is that these have 1.8kΩ pullups to 3.3V to facilitate I²C use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean GPIO 2 and 3 (pins 3 and 5).

They will be ordinary GPIO unless you set them as the I2C bus.

So as long as you don't have an I2C entry in `/boot/config.txt` you need do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your /boot/config.txt contains the lines:

`dtparam=i2c_arm=off
dtparam=i2s=off`

then you will have "normal" GPIO on those pins.

Comment: I think the second line here should be:
dtparam=i2c=off
instead of i2s